# KIBANA: can I edit the event onclick over one chart(histogram-piechart)?

Tags: javascript, kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5, kibana-3

I made an histogram on kibana dashboard and until here everything is fine.

When I click over one column happen this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me797.png

I really don't like this visual whit just the one big column selected so I want to edit the "onclick event" and made like "change color" and doing something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c6Aa.png

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with kibana.
But you can use [kibana API plugin](https://github.com/Webiks/kibana-API) and switch chart.
if the chart  not relevant any more, because you see only one column, you can create new chart dynamically and replace chart.
This plugin work in kibana iframe embedded only

Comment: can you explain please how it works? I putted in my code and in the inspector there is no error but, looking through on the code, I see that there is no trigger event like "on click" => "do this". Actually I have html with the iframe and the js is empty. I just putted the code suggested in the page that you suggested

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I want use the part of the plugin "Replace Visualization". where write I this code? https://github.com/Webiks/kibana-API/wiki/Replace-Visualization

Comment: If you use embedded iframe as a dashboard, you need to write the code in you're application

Comment: You need to download the plugin zip file, unzip it to kibana plugin directory in you're computer, change kibana version in the package json to yours version, and restart kibana